# Mapping id values with event values in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dictionary

I'm new to javascript/jQuery and I'm trying to find the smartest way to trigger an event based on whether a id is active or not :

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li id="1" class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="2"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="3"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="4"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

It becomes a bit more difficult as the rule is as follow:

> if id=1 is active, trigger alert("A") if id=2 is active trigger
>   alert("B") if id=3 is active trigger alert("C") if id=4 is active
>   trigger alert("D")

What function could I use to map 1 with A, 2 with B etc. ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1.Don't use numbers as IDs

Comment: You can add a `click` listener to your `li`s , call a method and in the method , if the id has a class , give an alert statement

Comment: good tip but i'm more concerned about how to map the values: 1 with A, 2 with B etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var functionsMap = {
    "id1": function() { ... },
    "id2": function() { ... },
    ...
};

$('.tabs li').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    functionsMap[id]();
});
```

Of course add check if function exists for element with such id, etc...

Comment: Thanks, but the key here is the li being active, not the "click". Can we make it independent from the click event ?

Comment: Of course you can, just run such code: functionsMap[ $('.tabs .active').attr('id') ]()

Comment: Good thanks ! And final silly question: when you write `"id1": function() { ... },`, what should `...` be replaced with ?

Comment: there should be any logic you want. For example alert('A') for first functions, alert('B') for second one, some animation for third, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var call_arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

$('click a random button').click(function(){
    var ind = $('li.active').index();
    alert(call_arr[ind]); 
});
```

Comment: That's good however there are different buttons to make the li active. Can this be independent from the click event ?

Comment: @user2441947 you can wrap it in a function and call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    alert(data[$(this).index()].toUpperCase()); 
});
```